# Duplicate gitconfig entries cause push to fail

Tags: git

To start with git version 2.16.2
in both /etc/gitconfig and ${HOME}/.gitconfig I have the entries:

```
[remote "origin"]
    push = HEAD
```

When i try to push I get the following error:

```
$ git push
error: dst ref refs/heads/some/branch receives from more than one src.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git:/foo/bar/source.git'
```

If I instead use `git push origin some/branch`, it works.

if I comment out the config in `${HOME}/.gitconfig` then `git push` works

```
$ git push
Counting objects: 21, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21/21), 9.60 KiB | 3.20 MiB/s, done.
Total 21 (delta 11), reused 12 (delta 2)
```

Can someone explain why the duplication requires a longer `git push` ?

Comment: What do you see when you type `git remote -vv`?

Comment: `$ git remote -vv
origin git:/foo/bar/source.git (fetch)
origin git:/foo/bar/source.git (push)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `git push` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) says, in part:

> When the command line does not specify what to push with `<refspec>...` arguments or `--all`, `--mirror`, `--tags` options, the command finds the default `<refspec>` by consulting `remote.*.push` configuration ...

What it leaves out here is that Git reads configuration files by iterating over entries, calling various callback functions.  One registers the callback function to be called for some prefix.  In this case `git push` registers for callbacks for `remote.origin.push`.

It gets two callbacks.  One says:

```
HEAD
```

and the other says:

```
HEAD
```

which Git combines with `push.default`—presumably you have this set to `simple` or something similar, so that whatever your HEAD reference is, the refspec becomes, e.g.:

```
git push origin some/branch:some/branch some/branch:some/branch
```

This means that the target reference `some/branch` should be updated from two separate source references: `some/branch`, and `some/branch`.  Now, obviously (to you and me), these are the *same* source, so this isn't a problem—but the internal code to handle this thinks it is, and complains.